# python read single line from file as string

Tags: python

I have a text file with a bunch of numbers then another line of numbers and another and another etc. with n number of lines

how can I read it and store the lines into n number of strings?

Comment: I believe this is what you need: https://www.google.com/search?q=python+read+single+line+from+file+as+string

Comment: It's ironic that the link above now points right back to this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects).

Or specifically:

> **`file.readline([size])`**
>
> Read one entire line from the file. A trailing newline character is kept in the string (but may be absent when a file ends with an incomplete line). [[6]](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#id17) If the size argument is present and non-negative, it is a maximum byte count (including the trailing newline) and an incomplete line may be returned. When size is not 0, an empty string is returned only when EOF is encountered immediately.
>
> **`file.readlines([sizehint])`**
>
> Read until EOF using readline() and return a list containing the lines thus read. If the optional sizehint argument is present, instead of reading up to EOF, whole lines totalling approximately sizehint bytes (possibly after rounding up to an internal buffer size) are read. Objects implementing a file-like interface may choose to ignore sizehint if it cannot be implemented, or cannot be implemented efficiently.

Comment: Good resources, but I think that if this guy is new (which I think he is) he may not completely understand what this documentation means by some of this. I know I didn't understand what this stuff meant when I was starting out.

Comment: *I think that if this guy is new (which I think he is) he may not completely understand what this documentation means by some of this.* Isn't documentation there so that one can refer to it when he/she can't understand something??

Comment: naw I got everything, thanks:)

Comment: well that solves that issue efficiently. :)

Comment: just out of curiosity is the end of line character an actual character or just like 'there'

Comment: Yes, `"\n"` is the EOL (It is one character)..

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like, generally, what you want is `f.readlines()`. Specifically, check out [this Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) on how to do it. Your code to open and display a file line by line would look something like this, however:

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```

Alternatively, you could write to a list and then call it later:

```
#STEP 1
f = open("file.txt","r")
#STEP 2
linelist = f.readlines()
count = len(linelist)
#STEP 3
print(count)
input = input("display line number:")
print(lineList[input])
# STEP 4
f.close()
```

What this second code does, is as follows.

1. It opens the file for reading, and initiates a few variables to be used.
2. It runs through each line of your document and adds it to the list `lineList`
3. After it runs through every line in your document, it displays the number of lines total and asks you to pick a line to display. Then the code ends.
4. Close the file handle. If you're using a context manager (`with`), this is done automatically.

Comment: Maybe `line = f.readline()` No need of the `for`..?? it is one of the simplest things that OP is asking, he should have done some research..

Comment: ok I fixed my code, sorry for the mistakes.

Comment: I wanted the file to loop through the entire document, not just one line. I removed the `f.readline()` altogether (although it still might be useful depending on how he implements it) and just had the code read the whole document using the `for` loop.

Comment: Both your codes are implemented as methods of file objects.. The second's STEP 1,2 can be rewritten as `f = open('file.txt');lineList = f.readlines(); count = len(lineList)`